# How to grab commit from grep output

Tags: linux, command-line, grep

Say I call the following command in a git repo:

```
git log --oneline -n 10 | grep pattern
```

and it gives me the following output:

```
c95383f asdfasdf pattern
3e34762 asdfasdfsd pattern
```

How can I grab just the commit hash from the second line so that I can pipe it into another command?

Comment: are you always interested in the hash on the last line?

Comment: For this purpose yes, but it'd be cool to know how to get any arbitrary line

Comment: if you are using this interactively, you could use a tool like [`fzf`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) to easily select any line you like and then pipe it to `awk`, e.g. `git log --oneline -n 10 | fzf | awk '{ print $1 }' | other-command`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider `awk` for this:

```sh
git log --oneline -n 10 | awk '/pattern/ {print $1}'
```

Where `/pattern/` matches `pattern` in a line while `{print $1}` prints first field from a matching line.

Comment: How can I get `awk` to just print the last line of it's output?

Comment: To print just the first line use: `awk '/pattern/ {print $1; exit}'`

Comment: How about just the last line?

Comment: That would be: `awk '/pattern/ {s = $1} END {print s}'`

Answer (score 2):

My friend just showed me this:

```
git log --oneline -n 10 | grep pattern | awk 'END{print $1}'
```

But I'm interested to see if anyone has any different solutions.

Comment: With `awk` [you don't need to use `grep` first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69888477/548225)

Answer (score 1):

For the commits printed (ten in this case), print the hash of the **oldest commit matching `pattern`**:

```
git log --oneline -n 10 |
awk '$0 ~ /pattern/ {hash = $1} END {print hash}'
```

Same, but for the **Nth newest**:

```
git log --oneline -n 10 |
awk '$0 ~ /pattern/ && ++c==N {print $1}'
```

(use 1 for newest, or 2 for second newest, etc, N must be <= 10 in this example)

Print hash of **Nth newest commit (no pattern)**:

```
git log --oneline -n N |
awk 'END {print $1}'
```

Or

```
git log --oneline |
awk 'NR==N {print $1}'
```

Remember that `git log` has the options `--since`, `--after`, `--until`, and `--before`, which take a date as input.